# Get Text property with asp control

Tags: asp.net, text, controls, properties

I created control using code:

```
...Page_Load(...)
{
...
TextBox tBox = new TextBox();
tBox.ID ="SpecificID";
somePanel.Controls.Add(tBox);
...
}
```

How to get Text property with this control (like `SpecificID.Text`)???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextBox textBox = somePanel.FindControl("SpecificID") as TextBox;
string text = textBox.Text;
```

i assume "somePanel" you have referred  is a asp.net panel control you are using in the page.

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBox textBox = Form.FindControl("yourid") as TextBox
string text = textBox.Text
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        TextBox tBox = new TextBox();
        tBox.ID = "1";
        tBox.Text = "hi";
        form1.Controls.Add(tBox);

        string Text= tBox.Text;
```